# Codeigniter Select and Count MySQL Records

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Using `Codeigniter 3`, I would like to display all the records from a table in a `MySQL` database. I'd also like to include the number of records selected.

For example;

```
Showing x number of records;

record 1
record 2
record 3
etc
```

Currently I have the following (which works);

```
// select all records
public function selectRecords() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('records');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

// count all records 
public function countRecords() {
    $this->db->select('count(*) as count');
    $this->db->from('records');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

My question is do I need two separate queries in order to achieve this (`select and count`)?

Is there a more efficient way of achieving what I want?

Comment: You can display count as count(array) in view. No need to do any particular query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
public function selectRecords() 
{
    $query = $this->db->get('records');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
       $records = $query->result_array();
       $data['count'] = count($records);
       $data['all_records'] = $records;
       return $data;
    }  
}
```

Pass it to the view from your controller :

```
 $data = $this->model_name->selectRecords();
 /*print_r($data) to see the output*/
 $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

In view :

```
<?php echo $count .' number of records';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do only:

```
public function selectRecords() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('records');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and

```
$records = $this->selectRecords();
$count = count($records);
```

Answer (score 1):

In The first function itself you can get the count using `$query->num_rows()` function

```
public function selectRecords() {
   $return = array();
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('records');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $return['count']   =  $query->num_rows(); 
   $return['records'] =  $query->result_array();
   return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
it will help you to provide pagination for records

```
public function selectRecords($params = array(), $count = false) {

    $offset = isset($params['offset']) ? $params['offset'] : '';
    $limit = isset($params['limit']) ? $params['limit'] : '';
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('records');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($count) {
           return $this->db->get()->num_rows();
      }

      if (empty($offset) && !empty($limit)) {
           $this->db->limit($limit);
      }
      if (!empty($offset) && !empty($limit)) {
           $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
      }

      $result = $this->db->get()->result();
      return $result;
}
```